# What is github 'compare & pull request'

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

I am working on a `MeteorIntegration` (feature) branch that is published. I did a `git push` assuming the push was going to the checked-out branch `MeteorIntegration`:

And now I see the following on both `master` and `MeteorIntegration` branches.

[image: github snap]

I read github documentation: [Closing a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-a-pull-request) and [Tidying up Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/tidying-up-pull-requests) but that didn't help, possibly because I am not dealing with a pull request here?

**How do I get rid of this `compare & pull request`?**

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You don't actually have a pull request; GitHub just sees that you've pushed a branch, and is offering to create a pull request for it if you want.

If you don't care about that, just ignore it.  It's completely harmless and will go away as soon as GitHub doesn't think the branch is "recent".

Comment: Thank you for this nice explanation. I was worried, too. (._.)

Comment: I was worried too. I thought I might have mumbled a bit on a few of those runic `git` chants. I am glad my `git` wizardry worked out in the end, though! 

You have my upvote, Eevee! +1

Comment: Would be nice to be able to have an "ignore" button though...

Answer (score 1):

You should actually change your branch.
Go to your repository settings> scroll down to Default Branch>click the button with the arrows to toggle btw master/main and update.
This should reflect all the files and folders in your repository.

Comment: Good advice, but not at all related to the original question